# How to validate unique field in db with pydantic

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

For example i have usual DRF serializer with validate method which checks phone number unique. How can i do the same with Pydantic+sqlalchemy and then use it in fastapi endpoint like serializer.is_valid()?

```
    def validate(self, attrs):
        if User.objects.filter(username=attrs["phone_number"], phone_number=attrs["phone_number"]):
            raise ValidationError(PHONE_NUMBER_IS_ALREADY_TAKEN)

        check_password_complexity(attrs["password"])

        ConfirmationService(
            phone_number=attrs["phone_number"], scope=ConfirmationCodeScopeChoice.SIGN_UP, code=attrs["code"]
        ).is_valid()

        return attrs
```

Comment: This should probably be the task of a service class (seems you already have a ConfirmationService) or of a helper function in your application, and not as a validator in pydantic; in that case, move the `validate` function out to a separate part that handles adding users in your application (and define username/phone number as unique in your database.

Comment: Uniqueness constraints are like a cornerstone of relational databases. Why would you even bother implementing your own checks for that? Just set the field as unique in the relevant table and implement some graceful error handler.

Answer (score 0):

Pydantic allows to add validators : [Validatots](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/)

```
class UserBaseSchema(BaseModel):
  id: int
  phone_number: str
  ...

  class Config:
    orm_mode = True

  @validator('phone_number')
  def validate_unique_phone_number(cls, value):
    # query a user with the same phone number
    res = User.objects.filter(phone_number=value).all()
    if res:
      raise ValueError('phone number must be unique')
    return value
```

Comment: validator does not support async calls to db

Comment: there is an issue on this on https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/857 pydantic does not support async. You can just rely on your database constraints as @Daniil Fajnberg
suggested